# Understanding multinomial regression

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution

I have data from these set of experiments:
In each experiment I infect a neuron with a rabies virus. The virus climbs backwards across the axon of the infected cell and jumps across the synapse to the inputs of that cell. In these input cells it well express a marker gene.
The purpose of this is to trace the input cells to the cells I'm infecting (target cells).
Therefore in each experiment I obtain counts of all the infected input cells.

What I'd like to estimate is the effect of each target cell on these counts, relative to the grand mean.
I was thinking that a `multinomial` regression model is appropriate in this case, where the contrasts are set to the `contr.sum`option.

However, I'd like some help interpreting the coefficients estimated by the model.

If I simulate very simple data like this:

```
set.seed(1)
probs <- c(0.1,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.2)
mat.col <- rmultinom(1, as.integer(runif(1,50,150)), probs)
mat <- matrix(rep(mat.col,3),ncol=3)
inputs <- LETTERS[1:5]
targets <- letters[1:3]
df <- data.frame(input = c(unlist(apply(mat,2,function(x) rep(inputs ,x)))),target = rep(targets ,apply(mat,2,sum)))
```

where the counts produced by the two targets are identical, after fitting the model:

```
library(foreign)
library(nnet)
library(reshape2)

df$input <- factor(df$input,levels=inputs)
df$target <- factor(df$target,levels=targets)
fit <- multinom(input ~ target, data = df,contrasts = list(target = "contr.sum"))
```

I get:

```
summary(fit)$coefficients

  (Intercept)  target.exon1  target.exon2
B   0.6931475 -2.682397e-08 -2.682397e-08
C   1.5040775  1.502057e-07  1.502057e-07
D   0.9162909 -5.340499e-08 -5.340499e-08
E   1.0116010 -6.342754e-08 -6.342754e-08
```

I thought that since inputs C-E are all equal to or above the grand mean, their coefficients should be positive. So my question is why are they negative?

Comment: To calculate the odds ratio in a multinomial regression, you need to take the exponent of the coefficients, not use the raw values. This has a pretty good tutorial: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/output/stata_mlogit_output.htm